# Font scaling for different screen resolutions

Tags: gluon-mobile, gluon-desktop

Hi does anyone have any advice or links to docs for scaling my app fonts so their size is consistent cross different screen DPIs? In particular my fonts look good on my (osx) desktop build, but are very small on my (android) phone build. Thanks!

Comment: Try to use `em` units in your css files. See the [Devoxx app](https://github.com/devoxx/MyDevoxxGluon/tree/master/DevoxxClientMobile/src/main/resources/com/devoxx) and how to deal with different setups if required (for Android, iOS, phone and tablets)

Comment: Thanks José! I'll check it out.